# using logsumexp in softmax

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, softmax

I saw this equation in somebody's code which is an alternative approach to implementing the softmax in order to avoid underflow by division by large numbers.

softmax = e^(matrix - logaddexp(matrix)) = E^matrix / sumexp(matrix)

```
logsumexp = scipy.special.logsumexp(matrix, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
softmax = np.exp(matrix - logsumexp)
```

I understand that when you log equations that use division you would then subtract, i.e. log(1/2) = log(1) - log(2). However, in the implantation of the code above, shouldn't they also log the `matrix` in order to subract the `logsumexp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of working in log-space to avoid underflow requires that the *intermediate objects you use to track progress* are themselves on the log-scale --- you only convert back to regular scale at the end of the computation.  (If you use intermediate objects that are not on the log-scale then you introduce underflow at that point in the computation, which then defeats the whole purpose.)  Consequently, I strongly suspect that the object `matrix` is using values that are already measured on the log-scale, and therefore you do not need to take a logarithm of the elements of this object in the code.  I recommend you review the initial settings for this object to see if this is how things have been done.

Answer (score 1):

`matrix` is on the log scale. If `matrix` were not on the log scale, then you would only want to do `log(sum(matrix))` not `logsumexp(matrix)`.

To see why, write down the steps and work through the algebra. It should be quite apparent if you do the manipulations.